# How to convert a text file with one line of comma separated text to a file with each comma separated field on a new line

Tags: awk, solaris

I'm using an old Sun Solaris 2.5.1. I have several files with l line of comma separated data fields that I need converted to each field on a new line.  There are a variable amount of fields in each file.

i.e.

```
#cat recipe1
299834,43399,PRODUCT NAME HERE,4.02,344,MORE TEXT HERE,3423 etc...
```

NEEDS TO BE:

```
#cat recipe1
299834
43399
PRODUCT NAME HERE
4.02
344
MORE TEXT HERE
3423
etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

So you just mean convert commas to newlines?

`sed 's/,/\n/g' in.txt > out.txt`

Looks like old Solaris doesn't have the special \n sequence. Try doing it with a real newline character:

```
sed 's/,/\
/g' in.txt > out.txt
```

Edit: updated to add backslash as suggested by @Ed Morton

Comment: Yes - that's what I want.

Comment: When I enter the proposed string - I get commas replaced by "n" instead of new lines...

Comment: Updated my answer because I couldn't get the formatting properly in the comment.

Comment: The portable way to get a newline in sed is a backslash followed by a literal newline character, so like your second script but with a backslash at the end of the first line.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps:

```
tr ',' '\r' < in > out
```

Comment: YES!  It was actually '\n' as itsmejodie suggested so thanks to you both. I can finally go home now - hopefully I can get the rest of this done tomorrow and call it a week...

Comment: To clarify, it was: tr ',' '\n' < infile > outfile

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `awk`:

```
awk '$1=$1' RS=, recipe1
```

But it will fail if there are `0` in the file, so better use:

```
awk '{$1=$1}1' RS=, recipe1
299834
43399
PRODUCT NAME HERE
4.02
344
MORE TEXT HERE
3423
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -pi -e 's/,/\n/g' your_file
```

**PS:** This command will do an in place replacement. So No need to redirect the output to a new file. Exiting file itself will be modified.